# "This page isn't redirecting properly"

Tags: tails

It's about accessing the login page of a certain site (starting with https://www.) using one of 3 different ways:

1. On a Debian 9.9.0 with Firefox 60.6.1esr access to that site is fine and requires no settings change.
2. On the same Debian with Tor Browser 8.0.9 access to that site is possible but requires settings changes.
   Under Preferences > General > Network Proxy > Settings

   - Check "Use system proxy settings" or "No proxy"
   - Uncheck "Proxy DNS when using SOCKS v5"
3. With Tails 3.13.2 no combination of Network Proxy Settings leads to the login page of that site. I get one or the other of the following messages:

   - "Unable to connect "
   - "Unable to find the proxy server"
   - "This page isn't redirecting properly"

Accepting or blocking cookies makes no difference.

In all 3 cases it's the same computer and the same ISP provider.

In cases 1 & 2 the information about the web site is identical and looks fine (to me at least). In case 3 it's unknown.

The user agent for each case:

1. Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0
2. Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0
3. Same as 2.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
Lately I've tried with Tails 3.14, the latest version, and I get the exact same outcome. Could somebody give me a suggestion on how to investigate further? Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Months later that particular site started to reject upfront the access with a bogus privacy violation message, but only when using Tor network. I've come to the conclusion that that particular site detect and reject whatever come from a Tor exit node.

Comment: That is not at all surprising. This is becoming more common. I actually had an onion site I was visiting reject Tor traffic yesterday because the onion site was just a mirror of the clearnet site.